# Woocommerce: Set thumbnail detail (clipping area)

Tags: plugins, thumbnails, cropping

I am using the german Wordpress 3.5.1–de_DE with Woocommerce 2.0.8 and the Woothemes Mystile Theme 1.2.8.

I have a big picture for a product (Jellyfish.jpg) and want to use a specific area of that big picture as a thumbnail, because Wordpress/Woocommerce automatically chooses a not useful part of the image. So I used the Wordpress crop tool in Edit Image under Media to generate a 150x150 thumbnail. This sucessfully generates a thumbnail (like Jellyfish-e1367238219134-150x150.jpg) but WP/Woocommerce uses another image (Jellyfish-150x150.jpg).

On my FTP I found the following files in /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/

> 012 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:56 Jellyfish-150x112.jpg
>   015 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:56 Jellyfish-150x150.jpg
>   026 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:56 Jellyfish-300x225.jpg
>   082 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:11 Jellyfish-787x300.jpg
>   009 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:56 Jellyfish-90x67.jpg
>   017 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:23 Jellyfish-e1367238219134-150x150.jpg
>   016 KB 0666   29.04.2013 14:58 Jellyfish-e1367240287874-150x150.jpg
>   758 KB 0666   29.04.2013 13:34 Jellyfish.jpg

I searched in the template and the plugin but it seems like they simple just use [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) and output the Jellyfish-150x150.jpg image (which is the useless autogenerated thumbnail).

Am I doing something wrong? What is the Jellyfish-e1367238219134-150x150.jpg image for? How can I choose which part of the image I want to show as a thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this using the following code snippet from Brian Krogsard, that I modified. This code should preferably be placed into the functions.php file of your child theme. Instead of taking the original 150x150 thumb it now takes the correct, cropped 150x150 thumb.

```
/* This snippet removes the action that inserts thumbnails to products in teh loop
* and re-adds the function customized with our wrapper in it.
* It applies to all archives with products.
*
* @original plugin: WooCommerce
* @author of snippet: Brian Krogsard
*/

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

/**
* WooCommerce Loop Product Thumbs
**/
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    }
}


/**
* WooCommerce Product Thumbnail
**/
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog', $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0 ) {
        global $post, $woocommerce;

        if ( ! $placeholder_width ) $placeholder_width = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_width' );
        if ( ! $placeholder_height )$placeholder_height = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_height' );

        $output = '';

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(150, 150) );
        } else {
            $output .= '<img src="'. woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() .'" alt="Placeholder" width="' . $placeholder_width . '" height="' . $placeholder_height . '" />';
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*e1367238219134-150x150.jpg` files are automatically generated by Wordpress as work copies once you save an image after editing it.

In order to use another image on your theme, you would want to contract a coder to modify your the pertinent template files.